# Replicate Finder's behaviour when mounting SMB share with mount

Tags: finder, mount, smb

I'm trying to mount a smb share on Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71). It works perfectly using Finder (`open smb://username@host/Directory`), it asks for my password and mounts it successfully, but I can't make it work using `mount` or `mount_smbfs` in a shell script. Whatever options I try, I always get `mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error`. Any ideas?

Logs I can see in MacOS console, could be probably relevant?

```
13:49:05.523744+0100    mount_smbfs networkd_settings_read_from_file initialized networkd settings by reading plist directly
13:49:05.523910+0100    mount_smbfs networkd_settings_read_from_file initialized networkd settings by reading plist directly
13:49:05.725745+0100    mount_smbfs [0x600001ad4000] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.cfprefsd.daemon
13:49:05.725869+0100    mount_smbfs [0x600001adc000] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.cfprefsd.agent
13:49:05.731324+0100    mount_smbfs [0x600001ad40f0] activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.GSSCred
13:49:11.913352+0100    mount_smbfs Adding PA mech: SRP
13:49:11.913392+0100    mount_smbfs Adding PA mech: ENCRYPTED_CHALLENGE
13:49:11.913415+0100    mount_smbfs Adding PA mech: ENCRYPTED_TIMESTAMP
13:49:11.913438+0100    mount_smbfs krb5_get_init_creds: loop 1
13:49:11.913459+0100    mount_smbfs KDC sent 0 patypes
13:49:11.913486+0100    mount_smbfs fast disabled, not doing any fast wrapping
13:49:11.915615+0100    mount_smbfs Trying to find service kdc for realm LOCAL flags 0
13:49:11.917267+0100    mount_smbfs configuration file for realm LOCAL not found
13:49:11.917285+0100    mount_smbfs Configuration exists for realm LOCAL, wont go to DNS
13:49:11.917301+0100    mount_smbfs out of hosts, waiting for replies
13:49:11.917319+0100    mount_smbfs no more hosts to send/recv packets to/from trying to pulling more hosts
13:49:11.917340+0100    mount_smbfs krb5_sendto_context LOCAL done: -1765328228 hosts 0 packets 0 wc: 0.003789 nr: 0.000000 kh: 0.001631 tid: 00000000
```